# WPF app with multiple usercontrols

Tags: wpf, user-controls, garbage-collection

I Am creating simple WPF test project which contains multiple UserControls(Insteda  of Pages).I Am using Switcher Class to navigate between different UserControls.When i navigate to different pages,i have observed that memory consuption keep on increasing on each UserControle Navigationand GC is not invoked.

```
    1.So am i doing something wrong in following code? 
    2.Which part of the code consuming more memory? 
    3.Do i need to invoke GC for disposing my UserControls on each new UserControle creation? 
      If need how can i invoke GC?


public void On_Navigate_Click()
    {
        UserControle newusercontrole=new UserControle();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds=con.getSome_Datafrom_SQL();//Gets data from SQL via connection class
        dataGrid_test.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;

        Grid.SetColumn(newusercontrole, 1);//dataGrid_test is inside newusercontrole and following is the code to add "this"  usercontrol to the main window.
        Grid.SetRow(newusercontrole, 1);
        Grid.SetZIndex(newusercontrole, 10);
        Container.Children.Add(newusercontrole);
    }
```

Comment: You are creating a new usercontrol and putting it into the children collection every time the button is clicked. How is the previous UC removed from the children collection? If there is still a reference to the prev. UC,  GC won't collect.

Comment: Yes now i changed my code. Before adding new UserControl am removing previous UC as below.   
Container.Children.Remove(oldusercontrole);
Still their is lot of memory leak.

Comment: Container.Children.Remove(oldusercontrole);
its working..
thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I must point out that if garbage collection really isn't happening (as you said), it's *not* your fault and it does *not* mean you're doing something wrong. It only means that the CLR doesn't think that your system is under memory pressure yet.

Now, to manually invoke a garbage collection cycle anyway, you can use the `GC.Collect()` static method. If a garbage collection actually starts and your memory consumption is still unreasonably high, this means that you're probably doing something wrong: You're keeping an ever increasing number of unnecessary object references and the garbage collector cannot safely collect those objects. This is a kind of a memory leak.

As far as your code goes, I think that the problem is at the end of the method you posted:

```
Container.Children.Add(newusercontrole);
```

This seems to add a new object (on every click) to the collection `Container.Children`. If this is not removed elsewhere, this is probably the cause of your memory leak. I don't know what the suitable solution would be for your use case (since I don't know exactly how your UI should behave), but you'll likely need to find a way to remove the last `UserControle` added from the `Container.Children`. If you can use LINQ, then the methods `OfType<T>()` and `Last()` could be of use to find it.

In any case, don't leave the `GC.Collect()` line in production code. Use it only to force a collection cycle for testing purposes, like this one.